# ElasticSearch - Restore Index to lower version

Tags: elasticsearch, restore, elasticsearch-5

I have some indexes in a ElasticSearch 6.2.2 installation and because of some requirements I might be downgrading to ES 5.6.4

Q: Can I take a backup of the indexes of 6.2.2 and restore them to 5.6.4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No this is absolutely not compatible in that way.

But you can may be reindex your data though. You can use logstash to read from the 6.2.2 cluster and write to the 5.6.4 cluster. It's not snapshot and restore but a way to workaround this.